# Why do some other people use dek and el rather than letters as the eleventh and twelfth digits in the dozenal or duodecimal system?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've noticed on a YouTube video titled [Base $12$ - Numberphile](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=U6xJfP7-HCc) that some other people who use the duodecimal system use dek and el for the eleventh and twelfth digits.  I know for one thing that them plus the regular digits equals twelve digits using base $12$, but why do they use additional digits that differ from the first two letters of the English alphabet?

Comment: Amazing, just amazing!  Great thing you spotted there.  Remember to answer the question if you have something good enough like there!

Comment: I am often too lazy to put 1 or 2 sentence answers as an answer instead of as a comment.  I don't really consider it enough work to warrant a reward.  If you like it as an answer so the question can be closed, I'd be happy to repost what I said below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, It works fine if you use a's and b's, but they tried to use names for "ten" and "eleven" which suggest their meaning. "dek" from "decem", coming from the latin word for 10, and "el" from "eleven", coming from the english word eleven.

It was a stylistic choice and nothing more.

Comment: "deka" is the Greek word for ten. It looks closer to dek than decem.

Answer (score 1):

The system has twelve digits which are: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 dek el and 10(means 12). 
The twelfth number is called Do(pronounced Dough) and comes from the prefix dodec-. This system is very useful for dividing $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ as 12 can divide evenly by 3 and 4. So: $\frac{1}{3}$ becomes $\frac{4}{12}$ so in the system $\frac{1}{3}$ equals 0.4. And as in $\frac{1}{4}$, it becomes $\frac{3}{12}$= 0.3 Which is why people love this system