# Why do some other people say do for $12$, gro for $144$, and mo for $1,728$ when they use base $12$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I heard on YouTube that do is some people's word for $12$ in the duodecimal system, but they also say gro for $144$ because it's a gross ($12$ dozens) and mo for $1,728$.  I think it's amazing, but why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

similar to my answer at [Why do some other people use dek and el rather than letters as the eleventh and twelfth digits in the dozenal or duodecimal system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108661/why-do-some-other-people-use-dek-and-el-rather-than-letters-as-the-eleventh-and), it is stylistic choice.  They could have defined the number $9+3$ (what we commonly know as twelve) to be named "frank" and what we commonly know as twelve squared to be named "obama".  There is no one way to name something, and so the "reason why" is not anything beyond aesthetics or history.  They chose "do" and "gro" because it reminds us of the words "dozen" and "gross", nothing more, nothing less.

An interesting note, the words that are in use today to refer to numbers is not standard around the world.  Take "billion" for example.  In the USA "1 billion" refers to "one thousand millions" = $10^9=1, 000, 000,000$ whereas in the UK "1 billion refers to "one million millions" = $10^{12} = 1,000,000,000,000$.  Similarly, in the USA "1 trillion" refers to "one thousand billions(US definition)" = $10^{12}$ while in the UK "1 trillion" refers to "one million billions(UK definition)" = $10^{18}$

There is nothing incorrect about either, though it is unfortunate that it isn't standard.  Why is a billion defined that way?  History.

Comment: A British billion **used to be** a million millions [but now](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/how-many-is-a-billion) it's a thousand millions, same as an American billion.